# C# - blocking GetRequestStream()

Tags: c#, solr, httpwebrequest, aerospike

I'm trying to get some data from Aerospike into SOLR, but I'm having a little problem with the web requests to SOLR. I'm using c#-s HttpWebRequest for the web requests on multiple threads. After a few batches the process gets blocked.
I found out that the code stops at the `data = request.GetRequestStream();` line, no exceptions, no messages, no timeouts it just waits and does nothing.
Here is a part of my code:

```
public static ConcurrentBag<String> docs = new ConcurrentBag<String>();
public static int count { get; set; }

<< data extraction into the "docs" container >>

if (count == 50)
{
    string dataStr = "{";
    string temp;
    lock (docs)
    {
        while (!docs.IsEmpty)
        {
            docs.TryTake(out temp);
            dataStr += temp;
        }
    }
    dataStr = dataStr.ToString().Remove(dataStr.ToString().Length - 1) + "}";
    count = 0;
    string SOLRInsert = "http://192.168.23.28:8985/solr/test/update";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SOLRInsert);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";
    byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataStr);
    request.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
    request.Proxy = null;

    Stream data = null;

    try
    {
        data = request.GetRequestStream();
        sw.Start();
        data.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
        sw.Stop();
        //data.Close();
        data.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(key.userKey.ToString() + "->" + ex.ToString() + "\r\n");
        File.AppendAllText(@"import.log", key.userKey.ToString() + "->" + ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            //data.Close();
            data.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are not calling `GetResponse` on that request so how do you know it went fine?

Comment: from the SOLR logs and the doc count on SOLR docs, I skipped the response checking for time optimization, at the beginning I checked the response too, but after some optimizations I saw it isn't necessary for me

Comment: And if you will check response (and dispose it after that) - you will still have the same issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback, I checked the responses and I found random errors while sending "}" as a document which returned 400. I solved the problem, so I have no more trouble with the requests. But I still have issues with the aerospike's scanAll function. It seems its not returning all of the data, at least with this incrementation in every thread `totalRead = Interlocked.Increment(ref totalRead);` I get a lower doc count value than I have in the aerosoike DB. Is it possible that this incrementation isn't thread-safe?

Comment: Interlocked.Increment is thread safe but you are using it wrong. You assign the result back into the variable and this is not thread safe, and you don't need that anyway. Just do Interlocked.Increment(ref totalRead), without assignment.